# Custom font doesn't work in IE8 in Zope/Plone

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, plone, font-face, zope

I'm making a Web Portal using Zope/Plone4 CMS.

Well, I used `@font-face` to declare the typography for headings.
The code and font are from Font-squirrel.
I made the website in local machine (without install the font in my PC) and everything works fine.
But in Plone, IE8 doesn't render the font at all. ONLY IE8, when IE7 and IE9 renders perfectly (?)

I made a test using Google Fonts. Everything works fine, all browsers.

I think it's possible that the error come from read/write permissions or something, because the font **doesn't render at all** in any IE if I was logged out.
This explains why Google Fonts render correctly (font is hosted outside Plone). But doesn't explain the only-IE8 issue...

I post the code here, well, I think is irrelevant, but if it helps...

```
     @font-face {
        font-family: 'TeXGyreAdventorRegular';
        src: url('../font/texgyreadventor-regular-webfont.eot');
        src: url('../font/texgyreadventor-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('../font/texgyreadventor-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('../font/texgyreadventor-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('../font/texgyreadventor-regular-webfont.svg#TeXGyreAdventorRegular') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
     }

     h1 {font-family:'TeXGyreAdventorRegular'}
```

I'm not Zope developer and don't have programming skills, Don't know if I'm looking for a solution in right way. I mean, I think CSS is correct and the problem comes from other side. But want to exploit all posibilities in my hand before definitely abandoned custom fonts from this site.

Note: Google Fonts works right, but all the fonts I have tested render very awful in Windows, and the site must be very accesible (and perfect legible). I prefer to avoid it.

Comment: What happens if you try to access the `../font/texgyreadventor-regular-webfont.eot` URL directly, as an anonymous user? How was the file added to your Plone site?

Comment: The browser downloads the font (well... request me from save the *.eot file or open it, you know). The file was uploaded directly from the manage interface.

Comment: Yes, and I think that that is the part that fails. I am trying to determine what the cause might be.

Comment: If it helps, we tried to upload the fonts manually too. In any folder (at the structure folder of the CMS) or directly in the root. Results are the same... I'm so confused that hurts myself in my confusion!

Comment: This should be part of the skin (so together with the CSS), not the content.

Comment: @Arkana: Just stumbled over this post, does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395722/webfont-not-working-in-internet-explorer help? And would you mind, if I flag this quest as a dup, then? (I know, you were first, but the explanation is in the other quest now already, too lazy to rewrite)

Comment: @IdaEbkes well, in fact there is not the same question... the other OP  can't make the fonts working in any version of IE... my error is only with IE8. Thanks at all! ;)

Answer (score -1):

You have to add an .eot (Embedded Open Type) file. This format was created by Microsoft over 15 years ago. It’s the only format that IE8 and below will recognize when using @font-face.

You can make one easily by using the free converter [ttf2oet](http://code.google.com/p/ttf2eot/)

Comment: As you see in the question, the first font is EOT. Also with a fix for explorer-only.