# Webfont not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, plone, webfonts

I'm using a webfont which is hosted by fonts.com. It renders normally in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, but not in any version of Internet Explorer. Even IE10 is not rendering it.

The project runs with Plone. The css file is registered normally via Cssregestry. But this shouldn't make any difference to a normal site.

To all who are familiar with Plone, this is the registry:

```
<stylesheet
    bundle="aufhebenswert"
    id="http://fast.fonts.com/cssapi/47bc7d51-3bb8-428d-a077-06d3d6f54eae.css"
    insert-after="*"
    cacheable="False"
    compression="none"
    cookable="False"
    enabled="True"
    media="screen"
    rel="stylesheet"
    rendering="link"/>
```

to all others, this is was appears in the HTML site:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://fast.fonts.com/cssapi/47bc7d51-3bb8-428d-a077-06d3d6f54eae.css">
```

In IE the link is rendered exactly like in chrome or FF , ...

Sadly I couldn't find any solution in other questions that have been asked here before. Also google search haven't been successful.

Is there any known issue or did I do something wrong?

Officially the fonts.com fonts should work in IE 4 and upper versions.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the missing local source for the fonts in the applied stylesheet:

`src: local(fontfamilyname) local(fontname)`

Which might be related to the `++resource++`-paths used in Plone.

The stylesheet seems to be protected with an authentification-mechanism, because applying the stylesheet directly from the given url into a test-template works fine, whereas applying a local copy of it, not.

Does your font-provider let you get the actual font-files or custom the stylesheet? If yes, apply local copies of the font-files and the stylesheet, replace the font-URL with your Plone-product-URL and supplement the style-rules with the local sources.

Comment: Sadly there isn't any way to do this. The provides doesn't provide the fonts itself or custom stylesheets. I haven't found any solution till now. The only thing that made it a better was using an alternative font that comes close to this one... :/

Comment: Yes, even if I have strong reservations towards google-services, I have to admit, that I really like the googlefonts-project, providing 'really free' fonts. Of yourse you might also just buy your favourite font. If you ever get actual font-files in your hands (always better then externally served, imho) and can approve my answer, an acceptance would be appreciated, as I have have tested this positive.

Comment: http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax seems to be helpful, too.