# Resize event in IE8 doesn't work. Plone error? IE8 bug?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, zooming, keyboard-shortcuts, plone, zope

I have a webportal in Zope/Plone. I have a JS that adds a new class in my `<body>`tag depends on screen size. This script is **working fine in IE7 and IE9**, even when you resizes the window, even when you zoom-in the page.

But in IE8 only works when you set the zoom through the Menu > View > Zoom. If you set the zoom level by shortcuts (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> / <kbd>crtl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>) ¡he totally ignores me, he, such an antistandard-unsocial-goodfornothing-washmachineprogramme!

Well, I have tried the code in my local computer and it works nice, even in keyboard zoom, even in "Menu" zoom, even in windows resize, and this make me suspect that something in our CMS (Plone) is interfering. But, *que me aspen*, I can't figure **what** the hell **is causing this strange behavior**.

[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NTn9k/) with the main code, if it helps.

**More strange details** 
If I set an interruption point in the JS to debug, IE8 works fine *in only one event*. That's very strange.

If I set an interruption in `$("body").addClass("c400");` IE8 works when the window is less than 800px (I see the pink background, however when I continue zooming until reach minus than 400px it stills pink).

**Other:** When I resize the window to the 800px width, IE8 don't fires me the event, ok. But if I press <kbd>alt</kbd> key (to view menu bar), the browser fires the event and I see the pink background, I can't understand nothing... it seems that IE8 is losing focus or something...

**It is possible....?**
I have posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900343/custom-font-doesnt-work-in-ie8-in-zope-plone) a few days ago. IE7 and IE9 renders the font properly but IE8 don't. It seems there's a few errors with Plone4 and IE8, but this can be only a coincidence...

Comment: I doubt plone is interfering with this; are you saying the Fiddle works for you in IE8?

Comment: that is bizarre. Can you disable all other plone js(in portal_javascript) and see if it still happens?

Comment: Yes, the fiddle works me with IE8. Well, in fact jsFiddle itself never works me in IE7-8 but if you copy the code in a local file and test it, it works... I'm feeling totally lost. I have disabled all the JS in Plone, except jQuery and my JS, of course, but still same behaviour.

Comment: I'm asking myself if the event that trigger the zoom event is different done by keyboard or by Menu > View... any idea?